# Simple AJAX callback

Tags: hooks, ajax

I'm looking to a way to make a call to a PHP function in my Drupal 6 module, and return the result asynchronously to the page.

I'm familiar with jQuery AJAX, but I don't understand how to post to a function using it. Does anyone have experience on doing this?

Comment: If you're trying to manipulate a form you'll need to use [AHAH](http://drupal.org/node/348475). If not, implementing a menu callback as jdu suggests is the way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've never done this with Drupal 6.

You want to use a [menu callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/group/menu/6): You create a menu item (which is just a path associated to a PHP function), and point your query request at that path.

Comment: Thanks, just run through the tutorial at http://viziontech.co.il/tutorial1 and got this up and running.